# Select count from another table to each row in result rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Classes](
    [ClassId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClassName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Classes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClassId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students](
    [StudentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClassId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Students] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StudentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Students]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_Classes] FOREIGN KEY([ClassId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Classes] ([ClassId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Students] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_Classes]
GO
```

I want to get list of class, and each class - the number of student which belong to each class.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to do this -

```
SELECT C.ClassId, C.ClassName, count(S.StudentId) AS studentCount
FROM CLASSES C LEFT JOIN STUDENTS S ON (C.ClassId=S.ClassId)
GROUP BY C.ClassId, C.ClassName
```

Comment: Like @Kshitij has indicated the difference between his query any mine will be that my query will omit any classes that don't have students  - hence the upvote :)

Comment: @Kane, I also think counting just the IDs should be more efficient, depending on how many columns there are per row, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like this?

```
SELECT C.[ClassName], COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Students'
FROM [dbo].[Classes] AS C
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Students] AS S ON S.[ClassId] = C.[ClassId]
GROUP BY C.[ClassName]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having to add the `group by` clause, you can do the following:

Create a function to get the students count:

```sql
go
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].GetStudentsCountByClass(@classId int) RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN
    declare @count as int

    select @count = count(*) from STUDENTS  
    where ClassId = @classId

    RETURN @count
END
```

then use it in your `select` statement

```sql
SELECT * , dbo.GetStudentsCountByClass(ClassId) AS StudentsCount
FROM Classes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT class.ClassId, count(student .StudentId) AS studentCount
FROM dbo.CLASSES class LEFT JOIN dbo.STUDENTS student ON (class.ClassId=student.ClassId)
GROUP BY class.ClassId
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com) accepts **code-only answer** like this, but it isn't *very* help for others. Please [edit] your answer and explain *How does your code work*. Sometimes, also *Why doesn't OP's code work*.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select c.ClassId,C.ClassName,COUNT(*) [Number of students]
 from Classes C,Students S
 where c.ClassId=S.ClassId
 group by C.ClassId,C.ClassName
```