# Need efficient SQL on joining rowcount from a materialized view with another materialized view

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Database Engine I'm Using**: PostgreSQL 9.5.2

**What I'm trying to do**:

I have the following two materialized views in my PostgreSQL:

1) **state_vendors_mat_view**

```
vendor_id    sol_id    states_list    total_revenue
---------    ------    -----------    -------------
1234         abc       CA, AZ         23000.00
5678         abc       TX, FL         12000.00
9012         def       AZ, TX         67000.00
```

2) **interested_vendors_mat_view**

```
sol_id    vendor_id    
------    ---------
abc       1234
def       5678
```

I'm trying to query the **state_vendors_mat_view** for a given sol_id (e.g. "abc"); however, I want to know, for each vendor_id in the result, is this vendor_id mapped to a sol_id in the **interested_vendors_mat_view**. If it is mapped, I want a Boolean value of true; otherwise, I want a Boolean value of false.

Furthermore, I want this query to be as efficient as possible. I don't want to run a select on the **interested_vendors_mat_view** for each record in the result from the **state_vendors_mat_view**.

**Desired Results**:

For example, if I want all vendors that have a sol_id = "abc", then I want the result to look like:

```
vendor_id    is_interested   sol_id    states_list    total_revenue
---------    -------------   ------    -----------    -------------
1234         True            abc       CA, AZ         23000.00
5678         False           abc       TX, FL         12000.00
```

**Notes**:

- The record for vendor_id=1234 has a Boolean value of True in the is_interested column because the interested_vendors_mat_view has a record that maps 1234 and "abc".
- The record for vendor_id=5678 has a Boolean value of False in the is_interested column because the interested_vendors_mat_view does not have a record that maps 5678 and "abc".

**Questions I've Looked At**:

- [Select count of rows in another table in a Postgres SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535782/select-count-of-rows-in-another-table-in-a-postgres-select-statement)
- [Select count from another table to each row in result rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113614/select-count-from-another-table-to-each-row-in-result-rows)

**SQL I've tried**:

```
SELECT 
 vendor_id, 
 CASE
    WHEN ((SELECT count(*) FROM interested_vendors_mat_view iv 
           WHERE sol_id = 'abc' and iv.vendor_id = state.vendor_id) = 0) 
    THEN false 
    ELSE true
 END AS is_interested,
 sol_id, 
 states_list,
 total_revenue
FROM state_vendors_mat_view state WHERE sol_id = 'abc';
```

To try and get just the correct row counts, I've also tried:

```
SELECT 
  state.vendor_id, 
  state.sol_id, 
  count(*)
FROM state_vendors_mat_view state 
 JOIN interested_vendors_mat_view iv ON (iv.vendor_id = state.vendor_id)
WHERE state.sol_id = 'abc' 
GROUP BY state.vendor_id, state.sol_id
```

> Neither of these give me the correct solution.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How does your query not work?  What is the correct result set and what result set are you getting?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The first query is giving me a True in each row for the is_interested column. The second query is giving me a total row count of the vendor_ids in the state_vendors_mat_view. I will try your SQL now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your query doesn't work, but it is perhaps because the comparison in the subquery uses `snid` rather than `sol_id` (which should generate an error according to the data formats in your question).

In any case, the query would more simply be expressed using `exists`:

```
SELECT sv.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from interested_vendors_mat_view iv
                where iv.vendor_id = sv.vendor_id and iv.sol_id = 'abc'
               )
       ) as is_interested
FROM state_vendors_mat_view sv
WHERE sv.sol_id = 'abc';
```

Comment: This SQL worked! Thank you so much! BTW: I meant the `snid` to be `sol_id` (updated my question).

Answer (score 2):

Consider a `LEFT JOIN` query with a conditional column calculation for `is_interested`, avoiding any subquery needs:

```
SELECT s.vendor_id, 
       CASE WHEN i.sol_id = 'abc' 
            THEN TRUE 
            ELSE FALSE 
       END AS is_interested, 
       s.sol_id, 
       s.states_list, 
       s.total_revenue
FROM state_vendors_mat_view s
LEFT JOIN interested_vendors_mat_view i
ON (s.sol_id = i.sol_id) AND (s.vendor_id = i.vendor_id)
WHERE s.sol_id = 'abc'
```

Comment: I will try this SQL as well. Thanks.

Comment: This SQL works as well. You were just missing an open paren in front on the CASE statement. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Good catch - in fact, no need for any parentheses. Let's hope future readers are helped.